# android app working in the background for notification

Tags: android, mobile, notifications, push-notification

I am developing an android app and having a problem on the notification part of the app. I am planning to push a notification whenever a new announcement is recorded to the database even if the user does not run the application. The scenario is like having a notification when a facebook user adds you as a friend. Even the user did not open the facebook app, the application ,in the background, shows a notification that says someone added you as a friend. In my app I am going to show announcements whenever an announcement is added to the database. For me the problem is how to make my app to work in the background to check whether there is an announcement newly added to the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not application in background, it's service working. Also you probably want to read about push notifications http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be writing your app as an android service..

Comment: Thank you so much Mohamed, I am gonna have a look at android service to handle it.